I have a problem with DrissionPage library
I use DrissionPage to access a site and retrieve data. The website I am trying to access uses cloudflare and I can bypass it with my code. But the site's search bar does not search.
I tried the loading strategy eagerly but still no results. I am using a proxy, in the same code, when I remove the proxy, the search bar works, but when I add a proxy, it does not work.

You need to create a minimal reproducible example. Don't just describe your code, show your code.
